# Flex + Dynamic adding Data into List

Tags: apache-flex, list

I'm totally new to Flex (moving away from Java for now :().

I have an XML file, I read the data and want to add it to a List and then use the List to be displayed.

Something like this is what I want to do:

List data = new ArrayList();

data.add(item1);
data.add(item2);

How can I do this, also how will I display the List in a table!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather... vague.

In Flex there are multiple ways to read data from XML and display it.
One approach would be using a `HttpService` to read the XML. 
Then you can loop through the data manually or serve it as a `DataProvider` for a `DataGrid`.

I suggest you take a look at the Flex documentation, flexexamples.com and the flex quickstart. Topics that could help you:

- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/httpservice/
- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/using_data_providers/
- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/07/26/displaying-xml-data-in-a-datagrid/

Comment: MysticEarth, your point is accepted, but I need to update an array/List with data, how can I do that without using Datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

Nerver mind folks, I figured it out myself :)

var hostList : Array=[];
                var i: int = numberOfHosts;

```
            var hostNames: XMLList = hostPointXMLList.elements("HostName");

            for (i=0; i< hostNames.length(); i++) {
                //Alert.show("num="+i+" Hostname="+hostNames[i]);
                hostList[i] = hostNames[i];
            }
```